# SQL unique pairs from bi-directional pairs

Tags: sql, hive

Given a table with bi-directional pairs i.e. A & B, B & A :

```
+-----------------------+
| Person_1 |   Person_2 |
+----------+------------+
| Nancy    |   John     |
| Nancy    |   Mary     |   
| John     |   Nancy    |
| Peter    |   Jane     |
| Jane     |   Peter    |
+----------+------------+
```

How to select only unique pairs in any direction, for example:

```
+-----------------------+
| Person_1 |   Person_2 |
+----------+------------+
| Nancy    |   John     |
| Nancy    |   Mary     |
| Peter    |   Jane     |   
+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
select person_1, person_2
from t
where person_1 < person_2
union al
select person_1, person_2
from t
where person_1 > person_2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.person_1 = t.person_2 and t2.person_2 = t.person_1);
```

This preserves the original ordering of the pairs -- so the rows returned are in the source data.  If that is not important:

```
select distinct least(person_1, person_2), greatest(person_1, person_2)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a correlated subquery with an `exists` condition:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 
    t1.person_1 < t.person_2 
    and exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.person_1 = t.person_2 and t1.person_2 = t.person_1
)
```